# What are these 15 types of handles called in Mandarin?

Tags: vocabulary

In English an assortment of things can be called "handles", and this is usually translated to one of the following in Mandarin:

> CC-CEDICT: **[把](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8A%8A)** (bǎ​) ... / handle / ...
> CC-CEDICT: **[把手](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8A%8A%E6%89%8B)** (bǎ​shou​) handle / grip / knob
> CC-CEDICT: **[手把](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%8B%E6%8A%8A)** (shǒu​bà​) handle
> CC-CEDICT: **[柄](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9F%84)** (bǐng​) handle or shaft (of an axe etc) / (of a flower, leaf or fruit) stem / ...
> CC-CEDICT: **[把柄](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8A%8A%E6%9F%84)** (bǎ​bǐng​) handle / ...
> CC-CEDICT: **[手柄](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%8B%E6%9F%84)** (shǒu​bǐng​) handle / ...

Here are 15 things which could be called "handles" in English:

> i. [image: Photo by Ron Lach from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/bicycle-handle-with-bell-10213675/]
> ii. [image: Photo by Tim Samuel from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/attentive-asian-male-taxi-driver-in-modern-car-5835451/]
> iii. [image: Photo by Anna Zaykina from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/close-up-shot-of-black-and-pink-door-with-gold-lining-8467502/]
> iv. [image: Photo by Leef Parks from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/brown-handle-knife-on-brown-wooden-table-3809174/]
> v. [image: Photo by Charlotte May from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/wooden-dresser-with-handles-in-room-5825540/]
>
> vi. [image: Photo by Luis Quintero from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-holding-black-backpack-3731256/]
> vii. [image: Photo by Jermaine Ulinwa from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/grayscale-photo-of-woman-holding-katana-3130928/]
> viii. [image: Photo by SHVETS production from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/empty-shopping-cart-on-yellow-background-7195232/]
> ix. [image: Photo by Skylar Kang from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/old-fashioned-handbag-with-metal-handle-6044266/]
> x. [image: Photo by EKATERINA BOLOVTSOVA from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/a-hand-holding-a-white-ceramic-mug-6312196/]
>
> xi. [image: Photo by Ferliana Febritasari from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/hanging-orange-handles-in-public-transport-3766617/]
> xii. [image: Photo by Tyler Lastovich from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/brown-and-silver-axe-on-grass-544458/]
> xiii. [image: Photo by Monstera from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/suitcase-with-world-map-in-room-7412055/]
> xiv. [image: Photo by Steve Johnson from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/photo-of-green-leaf-plant-near-white-wooden-cabinet-930602/]
> xv. [image: Photo by Mike B from Pexels: https://www.pexels.com/photo/red-scissors-near-green-leaf-211710/]
> (click to enlarge images; stock images from [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/))

**Question**: What are these 15 types of handles called in Mandarin?

This is what I think: i. 车柄 ii. 把手 iii. 把手 iv. 把柄 v. 把手 vi. 手柄 (??) vii. 剑柄 viii. 把手 ix. 手柄 (??) x. 把手 xi. 把手 xii. 把柄 xiii. 把手 xiv. 门把  xv. 把手 (??).

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule every handle can be translated as "把/把手". Aside from 把手 there are specific names given to specific types of handles/把手. For example:

iv./vii./xii. 柄

vi./ix. 提手

xi. 扶手 (including the poles, the seat handles and the grab/strap handles)

xi. 拉环 (the round-shaped grab/strap handles)

xiii. 拉杆

Answer (score 0):

槍把, 刀把, 劍把, 鍋把, 鍋蓋把, 杯把, 頩把, 車把, 提把, 門把, 窗把, 儲/櫥櫃把, 箱把,把手, 手把, 把柄.